# Automatically coerce all column types of one data frame to the type of another prior to binding

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have two data frames I want to bind:

```
ds_a <- data.frame(
  x = 1:6,
  y = 5,
  z = "4",
  l = 2,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ds_b <- data.frame(
  x = as.factor(1:6),
  y = "5",
  p = 2,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

When I try to bind them I get the following error:

```
> bind_rows(ds_a, ds_b)
Error: Can't combine `..1$x` <integer> and `..2$x` <factor<4c79c>>.
```

Typically what I do to solve this is I convert all the columns in both data frames to a character, bind the two data frames, and then manually re-convert all the columns back to their original type.

Is there a way to simply coerce all the type collisions between `ds_a` and `ds_b` by automatically casting `ds_b`'s columns to match `ds_a` (assuming they're named the same)?

More generally, I'd like a solution to automatically convert all the columns in `ds_b` to the type of `ds_a` wherever the column names match. And the solution should work if `ds_b` and `ds_a` don't share all the same columns (just filling with NA when columns don't exist in one, but do in another).

Here's the intended outcome:

```
ds_merged =read.table(text = 'x y z l p 
1 1 5 4 2 NA
2 2 5 4 2 NA
3 3 5 4 2 NA
4 4 5 4 2 NA
5 5 5 4 2 NA
6 6 5 4 2 NA
7 1 5 NA NA 2
8 2 5 NA NA 2
9 3 5 NA NA 2
10 4 5 NA NA 2
11 5 5 NA NA 2
12 6 5 NA NA 2', header = TRUE, row.names = NULL)

> ds_merged

   row.names x y  z  l  p
1          1 1 5  4  2 NA
2          2 2 5  4  2 NA
3          3 3 5  4  2 NA
4          4 4 5  4  2 NA
5          5 5 5  4  2 NA
6          6 6 5  4  2 NA
7          7 1 5 NA NA  2
8          8 2 5 NA NA  2
9          9 3 5 NA NA  2
10        10 4 5 NA NA  2
11        11 5 5 NA NA  2
12        12 6 5 NA NA  2
```

Comment: I don't think it's the job of the *binding* function to infer what class coercion should be done: if they match (or are unambiguous, such as `dbl` and `int`), great, if not then *assume nothing*. The user/programmer is the only one who really knows what class a column is supposed to be, anything else is inference and therefore prone to mistakes. `dplyr::bind_rows` makes some inferences/assumptions here, and I have yet to find where what it did was a mistake, but that does not mean (to me) that it is always the best stance to take.

Comment: I didn't say it was the job of a binding function, although the default behavior of rbind is to convert everything to character when there are class collisions. I'd just like a general solution for converting all the columns of one data frame to the type of another, so that no error is thrown upon binding.

Comment: I've run into situations where one time it converted to `character` and the other time it did not; I ended up having to deal with conditionally cleaning the data post-`rbind`, which is similar to verifying the data pre-`rbind`, except ... conversion to `character` and back to something else is not always lossless, which is why I suggest that it should be done before `rbind`ing altogether. Btw, my previous comment is not an attack on you to say you feel entitled to have `rbind` work better for you ... it was me saying I've been bitten too many times to trust inference or auto-`character` :-)

Comment: Gotcha, and I completely agree. No offense taken :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We could use `type.convert()`

**Explanation: after comment of OP:**

`type_convert` does not consider `ds_a` (you can check if you compare `glimpse(ds_a)` with `glimpse` of the resulting dataframe:

Note the columns of `ds_a` have the same classes as in `result`.

```
> # compare classes
> glimpse(ds_a)
Rows: 6
Columns: 4
$ x <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
$ y <dbl> 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
$ z <chr> "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"
$ l <dbl> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
> glimpse(ds_b)
Rows: 6
Columns: 3
$ x <fct> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
$ y <chr> "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5"
$ p <dbl> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
> glimpse(result)
Rows: 12
Columns: 5
$ x <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
$ y <dbl> 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
$ z <chr> "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ l <dbl> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ p <int> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

What `type.convert` does is:

1. to apply the best fitting class to the data of `ds_b` (notice the %>% is within `bind_rows`). So all of `ds_b$x` are integers therefore R converts class factor to class integer in ds_b$x.
2. All of `ds_b$y` are character class but integers in nature, therefore R converts character class to integer class. **This may cause the misleading understanding.** But, now we have `ds_a$y` double class and `ds_b$y` integer class -> but this is no problem for R and `bind_rows` here double class overrides integer.

```
> # showing what type.convert does to ds_b
> ds_b$x <- as.integer(ds_b$x)
> ds_b$y <- as.integer(ds_b$y)
> ds_b %>% 
+   as_tibble()
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      x     y     p
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     5     2
2     2     5     2
3     3     5     2
4     4     5     2
5     5     5     2
6     6     5     2
> ds_b %>% 
+   as_tibble()
# A tibble: 6 x 3
      x     y     p
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     5     2
2     2     5     2
3     3     5     2
4     4     5     2
5     5     5     2
6     6     5     2
> bind_rows(ds_a, ds_b) %>% 
+   as_tibble()
# A tibble: 12 x 5
       x     y z         l     p
   <int> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     5 4         2    NA
 2     2     5 4         2    NA
 3     3     5 4         2    NA
 4     4     5 4         2    NA
 5     5     5 4         2    NA
 6     6     5 4         2    NA
 7     1     5 NA       NA     2
 8     2     5 NA       NA     2
 9     3     5 NA       NA     2
10     4     5 NA       NA     2
11     5     5 NA       NA     2
12     6     5 NA       NA     2
```

3. converts `ds_b$p` which is class double to class integer because the data are integer in nature.

**Solution:**

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(ds_a, ds_b %>% type.convert(as.is=TRUE))
```

output:

```
   x y    z  l  p
1  1 5    4  2 NA
2  2 5    4  2 NA
3  3 5    4  2 NA
4  4 5    4  2 NA
5  5 5    4  2 NA
6  6 5    4  2 NA
7  1 5 <NA> NA  2
8  2 5 <NA> NA  2
9  3 5 <NA> NA  2
10 4 5 <NA> NA  2
11 5 5 <NA> NA  2
12 6 5 <NA> NA  2
```

Comment: How does `type_convert` know what the class types are of `ds_a` if it's only being applied to `ds_b`? It seems like it's just converting everything to an integer if you do it on `ds_b` alone?

Comment: And will this work if you have POSIXt-class column in `df_a`?

Comment: Please see my update! And with POSIXt-class in column `df_a`. This depends, the eye of the needle is `bind_rows`. So the task is to make each column that we try to bind is in the same kind of class. `type.convert` only assists to achieve this task.

Answer (score 9):

You can change the class of one dataframe according to another one and row bind the datasets.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

bind_rows(ds_a, map2_df(ds_b, map(ds_a, class), ~{class(.x) <- .y;.x}))

#   x y
#1  1 5
#2  2 5
#3  3 5
#4  4 5
#5  5 5
#6  6 5
#7  1 5
#8  2 5
#9  3 5
#10 4 5
#11 5 5
#12 6 5
```

`map2_df` is used to changes the class of `ds_b` data where

`.x` - passes the column value of `ds_b`.

`.y` - `map(ds_a, class)` gets the `class` of each column in `ds_a`

In the function it changes class of `.x` with `.y` value and bind them. We then use `bind_rows` with `ds_a` dataframe.

---

If there are unequal number of columns you can change the classes of only common ones and bind the rows.

```
new_bind <- function(a, b) {
  common_cols <- intersect(names(a), names(b))
  b[common_cols] <- map2_df(b[common_cols], 
               map(a[common_cols], class), ~{class(.x) <- .y;.x})
  bind_rows(a, b)  
}
new_bind(ds_a, ds_b) 

#   x y    z  l  p
#1  1 5    4  2 NA
#2  2 5    4  2 NA
#3  3 5    4  2 NA
#4  4 5    4  2 NA
#5  5 5    4  2 NA
#6  6 5    4  2 NA
#7  1 5 <NA> NA  2
#8  2 5 <NA> NA  2
#9  3 5 <NA> NA  2
#10 4 5 <NA> NA  2
#11 5 5 <NA> NA  2
#12 6 5 <NA> NA  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the base R code below

```
ds_a[setdiff(names(ds_b), names(ds_a))] <- NA
ds_b[setdiff(names(ds_a), names(ds_b))] <- NA
ds_merged <- list2DF(
  Map(
    function(x, y) {
      if (all(!is.na(y))) {
        class(x) <- class(y)
      }
      x
    },
    rbind(ds_a, ds_b),
    ds_a
  )
)
```

and you will get

```
> ds_merged
   x y    z  l  p
1  1 5    4  2 NA
2  2 5    4  2 NA
3  3 5    4  2 NA
4  4 5    4  2 NA
5  5 5    4  2 NA
6  6 5    4  2 NA
7  1 5 <NA> NA  2
8  2 5 <NA> NA  2
9  3 5 <NA> NA  2
10 4 5 <NA> NA  2
11 5 5 <NA> NA  2
12 6 5 <NA> NA  2

> str(ds_merged)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ y: num  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ z: chr  "4" "4" "4" "4" ...
 $ l: num  2 2 2 2 2 2 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ p: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` developers recommend `rbindlist()` for this apparently: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1162

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

list(ds_a, ds_b) %>% 
  data.table::rbindlist() 
#>     x y
#>  1: 1 5
#>  2: 2 5
#>  3: 3 5
#>  4: 4 5
#>  5: 5 5
#>  6: 6 5
#>  7: 1 5
#>  8: 2 5
#>  9: 3 5
#> 10: 4 5
#> 11: 5 5
#> 12: 6 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks for this, but in my actual dataset where the two data.frames to be bound don't share all the same columns, I'm getting `Error in data.table::rbindlist(., fill = TRUE) : Class attribute on column 1 of item 2 does not match with column 1 of item 1.`

Comment: And this seems to be a known issue? https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3911

Comment: Hmmm not sure. Here is a one-liner from another SO question that copies the data types from one df to another  
`ds_b[] <- mapply(FUN = as, ds_b, sapply(ds_a, class), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`

Comment: (That doesn't seem to work as well when you have a `POSIXt`-class column in the fray?)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

namesdif <- setdiff(names(ds_b),names(ds_a))

dfbind <- ds_a %>% 
  bind_cols(select(ds_b,all_of(namesdif)) %>% slice(1)) %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(namesdif), ~ NA))

reduce(1:nrow(ds_b), function(x,y)
{
  add_row(x, !!!setNames(rep(NA, ncol(x)), names(x)));
  x[y+nrow(ds_a),names(ds_b)] <- ds_b[y,];
  x
}, .init=dfbind)

#>    x y    z  l  p
#> 1  1 5    4  2 NA
#> 2  2 5    4  2 NA
#> 3  3 5    4  2 NA
#> 4  4 5    4  2 NA
#> 5  5 5    4  2 NA
#> 6  6 5    4  2 NA
#> 7  1 5 <NA> NA  2
#> 8  2 5 <NA> NA  2
#> 9  3 5 <NA> NA  2
#> 10 4 5 <NA> NA  2
#> 11 5 5 <NA> NA  2
#> 12 6 5 <NA> NA  2
```