# Modify a row from a column with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have these two tibbles

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

my_date <- as_date(c("2021-10-30","2021-10-29","2021-10-28"))
my_t1 <- tibble(date = my_date) %>% 
  mutate("col1" = NA, 
         "col2" = NA, 
         "col3" = NA, 
         "col4" = NA)
my_t2 <- tibble("column" =  c("col1","col2","col3","col4"), 
                "value" = c(10,20,30,40))
```

So

```
> my_t1
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  date       col1  col2  col3  col4 
  <date>     <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 2021-10-30 NA    NA    NA    NA   
2 2021-10-29 NA    NA    NA    NA   
3 2021-10-28 NA    NA    NA    NA  

> my_t2
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  column value
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 col1      10
2 col2      20
3 col3      30
4 col4      40
```

And I would like to copy the values of

```
my_t2 %>% select(value)
```

into one specific row of `my_t1`, say the middle row (with `date == "2021-10-29"`).
I would like to avoid doing for each element, one by one (i.e. base R) so that `my_t1` becomes

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  date       col1  col2  col3  col4 
  <date>     <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 2021-10-30 NA    NA    NA    NA   
2 2021-10-29 10    20    30    40   
3 2021-10-28 NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pivoting way making use of `coalesce` after defining id_groups:

**Update:** Shorter code with help from akrun!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_t1 %>%  pivot_longer(
  cols = -date, 
  names_to = "column",     
  values_to = "value"
  ) %>%    
  left_join(my_t2, by="column") %>% 
  transmute(date, column, value = case_when(date == '2021-10-29' ~ coalesce(value.x, value.y), TRUE ~ as.numeric(value.x))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = column, values_from = value)
```

**First answer:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_t1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -date, 
    names_to = "column",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>% 
  left_join(my_t2, by="column") %>% 
  group_by(id_Group = cumsum(column=="col1")) %>% 
  mutate(value.x = ifelse(id_Group==2, coalesce(value.x, value.y), value.x)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(date, column, value=value.x) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = column,
    values_from = value
  )
```

```
  date        col1  col2  col3  col4
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2021-10-30    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 2021-10-29    10    20    30    40
3 2021-10-28    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: You can skip a column of steps with `my_t1 %>%  pivot_longer(
    cols = -date, 
    names_to = "column",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>% 
  left_join(my_t2, by="column") %>% transmute(date, column, value = case_when(date == '2021-10-29' ~ coalesce(value.x, value.y), TRUE ~ as.numeric(value.x))) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = column, values_from = value)`

Answer (score 3):

We may use `match` with `cur_column` to `replace` the 2nd row with the corresponding 'column' value from 'my_t2'

```
library(dplyr)
my_t1_new <- my_t1 %>% 
    mutate(across(-date, ~ replace(., date == "2021-10-29", 
         my_t2$value[match(cur_column(), my_t2$column)])))
```

-output

```
my_t1_new
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  date        col1  col2  col3  col4
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2021-10-30    NA    NA    NA    NA
2 2021-10-29    10    20    30    40
3 2021-10-28    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

---

If the columns are in order, `base R` is easier

```
my_t1_new <- as.data.frame(my_t1)
my_t1_new[2, -1] <- my_t2$value
```

Comment: ,at:akrun: could you please check my answer here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69713760/automatically-coerce-all-columns-types-of-one-data-frame-to-the-type-of-another/69782214#69782214> and assist if it is not appropriate?!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option where you insert a new row and remove the old:

```
my_t1 %>% 
  add_row(date = as.Date("2021-10-29"), !!! deframe(my_t2), .before = 2) %>% 
  distinct(date, .keep_all = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `purrr::reduce`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

reduce(1:4, function(x,y) {x[x$date == "2021-10-29",y+1] <- my_t2[y,2]; x},
 .init=my_t1)

#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   date        col1  col2  col3  col4
#>   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2021-10-30    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 2 2021-10-29    10    20    30    40
#> 3 2021-10-28    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

---

Yet another solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

my_t1 %>% 
  bind_rows(
    data.frame(date = as_date("2021-10-29"), 
      pivot_wider(my_t2, names_from = column))) %>% 
  filter(!(date == "2021-10-29" & !complete.cases(.) )) %>% arrange(date)

#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   date        col1  col2  col3  col4
#>   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2021-10-28    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 2 2021-10-29    10    20    30    40
#> 3 2021-10-30    NA    NA    NA    NA
```